# How to sketch level curves of the form $f(x,y)= |x|+|y|$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves

I'm struggling to sketch the level curves of the equation $f(x,y)= |x|+|y|$
I know for finding the level curves you have to set $f(x,y) = C$ (with c a constant). But then I have the equation $|x|+|y|=C$.

So lets say $C=0$, then $|x|+|y|=0$, but how can I sketch this. Because both x and y are greater then zero, and they have to add up to 0, therefore x and y needs to be zero, but then I can't draw anything.

So lets say $C=1$,then $|x|+|y|=1$, but how can I sketch this. Can I say that $x + y= \pm1$, therefor $y=1-x$ and $y = 1+x$ (but $x$ can't be negative, so I don't know how do this problem.)

If you know the answer, it would be very much appreciated to help me

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $|x|>0$ is NOT the same as $x>0$! and also, the image of $x\mapsto |x|$ contains 0

Comment: so how can i sketch this then? Can I even sketch this for some constant C?

Comment: Have you heard of [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)? Try plotting your curves there and see if that helps.

Comment: I think I don't  understand what's the confusion. $|x|+|y|=0$ can be very easily sketched. the set of solutions is one point. Once you understand my earlier comment, it should be very easy to graph |x|+|y|=1 and you get all the other ones in a very similar way (or by scaling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x|+|y|=1$, consider four possibilities:

- $x,y\geqslant0$: then you just have $x+y=1$;
- $y\leqslant0\leqslant x$: then you just have $x-y=1$;
- $x,y\leqslant0$: then you just have $-x-y=1$;
- $x\leqslant0\leqslant y$: then you just have $-x+y=1$.

So, your curve is a square, expressed as the union of $4$ line segments. To be more precise: it's the square whose vertices are $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I just add a comment to the already proposed solutions.
Since $f(x,y) = f(-x, y) = f(x, -y) = f(-x, -y)$, the level sets of $f$ are symmetric w.r.t. the reflections about the axes $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$ and $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$,
and w.r.t. the symmetry about the origin $(x,y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$.

Given that, it is enough to draw the level set for example in the quadrant $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, and then you get the whole picture using the above symmetries.